# Using a listener for a tap inside a dom-if

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I have a simple button that I want to trigger something when pressed. I gave the button an `id` and created a listener for `id.tap`. This works fine, but when I put my button inside a `template[is=dom-if]` it stops working. Is this meant to work like this? How do I solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements inside a `dom-if` don't exist yet when the element is created, so they're not accessible using `this.$`. Either give the element an `on-tap` attribute, or use `Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector` to find the element.

Comment: Or just use this.$$(selector) for dynamically created nodes like dom-repeat and dom-if children.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer and addition. Why should I not just always use this.$$()? Then I don't need to think about it...

Comment: That's probably fine. I find `this.$.id` easier to type than `this.$$('#id')`. Know that `this.$$` has to do work every time to find the element, but the inefficiency probably isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 3):

FYI, the documentation recommends against the liberal use of `dom-if`.

> Since it is generally much faster to hide and show elements rather than destroy and recreate them, conditional templates are only useful to save initial creation cost when the elements being stamped are relatively heavyweight and the conditional may rarely (or never) be true in given usages. Otherwise, liberal use of conditional templates can actually add significant runtime performance overhead.

Using`hidden$=condition` might be the best solution.

Comment: Thanks! I'm using it to stamp only on creation, so it should be fine I guess.